# Monitoring solution for a few raspberry pis and a shared host

Tags: linux, monitoring, raspberry-pi

I currently run several raspberry pis at home for controlling my UniFi APs. Apart from that I have a backup server and a simple web server running an app that I develop myself. I also have like 5 websites I manage and I would like to monitor all these things in a simple but yet detailed UI.

I know there won't be many informations for the shared hosters where the pages run, but I expect a good amount of data that should be possible to gather from the PIs.

Now my requirements for the hardware are not that high. I personally would want to run it on a Raspberry PI 3 Model B+. The size of the SD card is flexible. What software can you guys recommend. I thought about Icinga but it seems a bit overkill. Another solution I found was [Pi Control](https://pi-control.de/) but that seems to only monitor one Pi. Another idea I had was writing my own solution but that seems a bit overkill. So what do you guys recommend?

Edit: Here is a list of my desired tasks:

- Watch the status of the MongoDB for my UniFi Controller
- Watch the status of the UniFi controller software
- Watch the status of the Raspberry PIs, Disk usage, RAM and CPU
- Watch the status of the internet and the speed of it
- Watch the status of several websites on a managed server, response time, up time
- Watch the status of several websites on a shared hoster, response time, up time

Nice to haves:

- Watch some wordpress blogs, with update availablitiy, uptime, response time
- Status of the UniFi APs, four of them

After researching I found Prometheus which looks promising, does someone have another recommendation?

Comment: Nagios! Always Nagios.

Comment: Monitorix might be worth looking into. See [these answers](/search?q=monitorix+is%3Aa).

Comment: What do you want to monitor? That they are up? Or some data that they collect? If "up" the Nagios, if collected data then Node Red and its dashboard)

Comment: For Nagios + R Pi, see item 6 on [this page](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/raspberry-pi-learn-online-security/)

Comment: @Mawg mainly the system load and disk usage. Also stuff like, if the internet is up, the state of the websites I manage. The status of the mongodb of my unifi controller and the unifi controller itself. I checked around and Prometheus looks like a good solution.

Comment: That makes it clearer. Please put it into the question, as not everyone reads all of the comments. In general, the more detail in the question, the more likely the chance of a satisfactory answer. *Maybe* Node Red? I have only just started looking at it myself, but it looks like a candidate.

Comment: [Somewhat related question](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/3930/which-free-dashboards-are-also-mqtt-brokers)

Comment: @Mawg I added my requirements with a few nice to have points.

Comment: Did you have a look at Node Red? Also, https://mydevices.com/

Comment: @Mawg yes I had, it doesn't seem like what I want. On mydevices.com I couldn't find a way to install it locally.

Comment: Cam you code? Maybe Python?

Comment: @mawg Yeah, that is actualy one of the solutions I thought about :D But I think I will settle with Prometheus and Grafana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time of researching and testing I settled with [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) for data collection, it is simply amazing what you can collect with it.

[Grafana](https://grafana.com/) for the diagrams and the monitoring watch screen and [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/) for storing the data.

Comment: Please accept your own answer, as that will help future readers. I edited your answer to provide links so that all of those future readers won't have to search :-) Btw, thanks for  those; I will certainly be looking into them.

Comment: Just did :) I really like it. The combination takes some resources though, I decided to use for each service its own Raspberry. I am really happy with the result.